# filter all threads containing (all) emails older than using gmail script

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail

My goal is to maintain dynamic labels 7d, 14d and 30d, which would list emails / threads from the last 7, 14 and 30days, respectively. I am happy, if the script will have one day error (i.e. listing some Sunday emails on a Monday 7 and half days later is OK with me).

In the process of learning to use the gMail scripts, I've got to something like this on my https://script.google.com/:

```
function remove7dlabel() {
// Every thread in your MailBox that is read, older than seven days.`
var threads = GmailApp.search('is:read older_than:7d newer_than:14d');
//newer_than is used to limit the number of thread for the removeFromThreads command; max 100
var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName("7d");
label.removeFromThreads(threads)
}
```

The script runs without errors, but the issue I have is the following: The "older_than:7d" query lists also threads that include mails newer than 7 days. This way, the "7d" label is removed from some older threads, which I replied yesterday (per example). Yes, it is true, those threads all contain some mails older than 7 days (and newer 14 days). I would like to filter threads with emails *all* older than 7 days. How can I do that? Do I have to do this on the mail level instead of the thread level?

p.s. The following source helped me source: http://www.johneday.com/422/time-based-gmail-filters-with-google-apps-script